# How to buffer entire video before playing by AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using a sample code of apple in a project. After customizing it's working fine, but when we play a video by url - it is not playing video properly. According to my requirement, is there any way to buffer entire video then play it?

Comment: Usually, AVPlayer will handle its own buffering.  Even if you can figure out how to make a URL point to a memory buffer, you are likely to cause memory usage problems on an iPhone, depending on the video size.  You might be better to explain what you mean by "not playing video properly" and see if there are fixes for that.

Comment: If you're playing from a server, you are going to get delays because of network timing.  The "requirement" you mention doesn't take into account the fact that disks are much faster and more reliable than wires.  If you have control of the server, here's one approach that might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

Comment: Another thought, what would be the advantage of buffering the whole video compared to downloading it to disk?  Getting it into memory still requires downloading, which is likely to **far** outweigh the disk writing time.

Comment: Means I was asking you…  How is buffering going to work if the video is on a server?